# Zurb Foundation 5, how to upgrade javascripts with compass?

Tags: javascript, installation, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

With Foundation 4, to update an existing project (not just the scss, but also the js files), you could do :

```
compass install -r zurb-foundation foundation/upgrade --force
```

This command now throws an error.

The Foundation 5 documentation only specifies :

```
foundation update
```

But this does not update the javascripts.

Anyone knows how to update everything...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install bower:

```
[sudo] npm install -g bower
```

then:

```
cd your_foundation_path
foundation update
```

all files into bower_components folder will be updated

Comment: This works of course, as they say in the foundation docs. And now it's the way to go. But I thought maybe I could update my old foundation 4 projects to version 5, while keeping my folder structure etc... kind of a straight forward migration, but it was not the case at the end.